# jqGrid - displaying grid in a dialog, popup or new page

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, popup, modal-dialog

Using jqGrid 4.5.2 & jQuery 1.9.1.  Querying a SQL table to return data to display results in a jqGrid.  I am not doing any editing of the data.

The jqGrid uses a `custom formatter` to display the results from the query.  Within the custom formatter, based on data returned (columns are hidden in the jqGrid), in a column called `Action` one of 3 things are shown: (1) a dropdown box, (2) a submit button, or (3) an informational message.  Additionally, `rowattr` is used to format (font, color, size, style) information in that row (also based on the data returned).  When a dropdown selection is made, that row then gets updated with the dropdown value & date/time.  Likewise, when the submit button is clicked, it also updates the table with a date/time.

The above runs on a `setInterval` every 60 seconds.  This grid functions as it is supposed to.

In addition to how the grid above works, I also need to conditionally build & launch another grid.  I would take the very same grid settings as used above, and the jqGrid would display in a dialog, popup or a new page.  I would query another table but return the same fields as I currently do.  This grid would also utilize the `custom formatter`, `rowattr` and other code (stopping & re-starting the interval, catching dropdown box changes & submit button clicks) as is done in the working `jqGrid`.  The main difference is that I would make an AJAX call to get a rowcount first, but only create the grid in the dialog/popup/new page if there was any data. The dropdown & submit button functionality for this grid would be the same as it is for the other grid (updates with a date/time and/or a dropdown selection).

I have been looking at building the dialog/popup grid inside a DIV on the page that currently has the functioning grid above on it.

```
<div id="popDailog">
  <table id="popGrid" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">
  </table>
  <div id="popPager"></div>
</div>
```

The existing, functioning grid is in the body of the HTML immediately above the DIV shown above:

```
<table id="myGrid" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  style="width: 100%">
</table>
<div id="pager1"></div>
```

My questions:

Can a jqGrid be built in a modal dialog box?  If not, how do you make it open in a popup or in a new page?  Most questions & answers I see deal with editing the data, but I am not doing that.

Can a jqGrid be conditionally built (are there options that control it)?  I want to avoid having to make two trips if possible.

I would appreciate any guidance or input as to if & how best to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Jquery code is not running in the modal dialog, so the caller can be run on, with open:

```
function initGrid() {
    jQuery("#popGrid").jqGrid({
    url:'...',
    colNames:[...],
    colModel:[...],
    rowNum:20,
    pager: '#popPager',
    ...
}

var dialog = $('#popDailog');
dialog.dialog({
    bgiframe: true,
    modal: true,
    width: 700,
    buttons: {...},
    (...)
    open: function(event, ui) { initGrid(); }
});
```